# Python If statements

Tags: python

In my python program sometimes in my if statements only the top one works

here is my program
http://ubuntuone.com/0u2NxROueIm9oLW9uQVXra

when you run the program if you go north east west south and then it doesn't work
the problem is in the function room4():

```
def room4():
    """Forest go south to small town room 1 and east to forest path room8"""
    room = 4
    print "Forest you can go south to small town, east to forest path, or continue to explore the forest"
    cmd = raw_input('> ') 
    cmd = cmd.lower()
    if cmd == "e" or cmd == "east" or "go east":
        print room8()
    if cmd == "s" or cmd == "south" or "go south":
        print room1()
    if cmd == "forest" or cmd == "explore" or cmd == "explore forest" or cmd == "explore the forest":
        print room13()
    else:
        print error()
        print room4()
```

Comment: Please put the code into the question so we can read it here without downloading.

Comment: Add `cmd == ` in front of your `go east` and `go south` commands - otherwise, they are evaluated as `True` always.

Comment: Is it just me or should you not be using `elif` instead of `if` in a lot of places in that file?

Comment: '*It doesn't work*' - please tell us how it doesn't work, what do you get, and how does that differ from what you expect? If you get an exception, post the stack trace.

Comment: @ crippledlambda is using elif better because they both seem to do the same thing

Comment: @wil The `else` will execute if the final `if` block is false, even if one of the former ones is true.

Comment: @wil `elif` and `if` are not the same. When an `elif` follows an `if` conditional, if the `if` conditional is false, then it will check if the `elif` is true. It will do the `elif` only if the previous `if` was false. As Lattyware said, the `else` is only executed when the last `if` or `elif` is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the future, please include the relevant code from your question.  I think you are referring to the following:

```
if cmd == "e" or cmd == "east" or "go east":
    print room8()
if cmd == "s" or cmd == "south" or "go south":
    print room1()
if cmd == "forest" or cmd == "explore" or cmd == "explore forest" or cmd == "explore the forest":
    print room13()
else:
    print error()
    print room4()
```

The reason that you will always enter the first `if` statement is that you have `or "go east"` instead of `or cmd == "go east"`.  Strings in a Boolean context (like in `if` statements) evaluate as true.

Instead of `if cmd == "e" or cmd == "east" or cmd == "go east"`, you could use the following:

```
if cmd in {"e", "east", "go east"}:
    ...
```

If you are in Python 2.6 or below where set literals do not exist, instead of `{"e", "east", "go east"}` use `set(("e", "east", "go east"))`.

Comment: Note that a nicer way of doing a test like this (with many options), rather than a lot of `or`s, is to do `if cmd in {"e", "east", "go east"}:`.

Comment: @Lattyware although due to set construction overhead - despite a set literal being more explicit - in this case using a tuple is more efficient and doesn't rely on 2.7+

Comment: @JonClements I imagine the difference is negligible in most cases, but you are right.